# Split in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, split

Here is my code below:

```
 vm.getid = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'api.json',
        })
            .then(function successCallback(data) {
                $scope.id = data.data;
                console.log($scope.id);
                $scope.split = $scope.id.split('/');
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log('error');
            });

    };
```

And here is my html, but it does not work :

```
<div ng-repeat="s in split">
  {{s}}
</div>
```

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/g1t4pludTTIAJYKTToCK?p=preview

I want to use **ng-repeat** `$scope.split`
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`$scope.id` is a list.

What you want to achieve is to get list of lists

The easy way to render it, to use 2 `ng-repeat`s

What about:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in id">
    <div ng-repeat="s in i.split('/')">
    {{s}}
  </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>[Demo 1](http://plnkr.co/edit/sxGWxubADWIzZVS0DoWu?p=preview)</kbd>

---

Or create `split` list as:

```
$scope.split = [];
angular.forEach($scope.id, function (item) {
    $scope.split.push(item.split('/'));
});
```

so HTML will look like:

```
<div ng-repeat="sp in split">
    <div ng-repeat="s in sp">
    sub: {{s}}
  </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>[Demo 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z8LvdNUFDB1vxkCRYYgB?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

printing out id you can see it is an array, not a string

```
["/big_big_package","/door/cooler","/door/chair","/door","/lets/go/deeper/than/this","/lets/go/deeper","/low"]
```

and trying to split it gives the following error in console

```
$scope.id.split is not a function
```

you can't split an array, you probably want to split each element in the array